# Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 2 notice

Tags: php

The below code is from a php book, when i run i am getting the message,
Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 2

```
 // This function will put all of the matches found into
 // the $matches array
    preg_match("/\d/", "1 and 2 and 3 and 4", $matches);
 // The 0 element of the $matches array holds another
 // array of the matches.
    echo "Value: " . $matches[0][2] . "\n";
```

should i have to use print_r instead of echo?

Comment: Look up what [`preg_match`](http://php.net/preg_match) does.

Answer (score 2):

`preg_match` doesn't set `$matches` to a multi-dimensional array. It's an array where `[0]` is the matched element, and the remaining elements are the matches for all the capture groups.

You should be using `preg_match_all`.

Comment: +1 Simply replacing `preg_match` with `preg_match_all` gives the expected output: `3`.